# ScrollView like on bottom Google Search app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking replicate the bottom bar like the google search app like this

[image]

i don't really sure if is a just a scroll horizontal listview or is another widget on android, i see the same behavior on the third party library called "Two-way" but i don't want use a third party libraries. thanks

Comment: checkout out the tab bar layout android.support.design.widget.TabLayout